# Create GWT project in Intellij IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, gwt

I'm beginner in using IntelliJ IDEA IDE and I want to create a new GWT project. I have added the GWT plugin to IntelliJ IDEA and now and I want to create a project. I googled but I didn't find a helpful tutorials or examples. Did you have guys a helpful tutorials to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you plan to do? For example, starting with the built-in gwt widgets, or something more modern like https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-ui/? Either way, I would encourage starting with either Maven or Gradle, adding GWT to it (as a dependency and a plugin as necessary), and letting IntelliJ import that.

Comment: A warning note before you continue reading, coming from someone (me) who's been developing GWT apps since 2016: **GWT is widely considered a dead framework**. See for yourself: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=gwt. The whole concept of transpiling Java to Javascript made sense 16 years ago, when jQuery didn't even exist, but JS development has evolved A LOT since then, making GWT obsolete. 1/2

Comment: It's been a decade since Google abandoned GWT development (it lives on as an open source project), and a couple years since IntelliJ stopped bundling the GWT plugin with IntelliJ Ultimate due to low usage. They still offer a separate plugin, but its functionality has slightly degraded over time (e.g. it no longer makes the connection *ServiceImpl→Service→ServiceAsync* when searching for usages, so IntelliJ thinks none of your *ServiceImpl* methods are ever used). If your goal is to learn web development, you'll make a better use of your learning time by picking a different framework. 2/2

Comment: GWT is a timeless (probably immortal ;) framework when it comes to developing (very) Rich Internet Applications in Java (limited to what makes sense in a web browser) heavily using object-orientation. What I like most about GWT is that you can establish a mostly seamless object-oriented architecture overarching client and server, e. g. to reuse your domain kernel. Consider kotlin as a more modern alternative (that is not yet timeless ;)! If you just need a web ui framework with an elaborate widget library GWT is not first choice - unless you want to build your own elaborate widget library.

Answer (score 0):

### **How to create a new GWT project in IntelliJ**

1. Create a new project: **File → New... → Project...**
2. Select **Java EE (Legacy)**.
3. Select **Java 8**.

   - *Do not use Java 9 or above unless you **know** what you're doing*. Yes, GWT 2.8.2+ works with Java 11+, but you'll need to open some internal modules for it to work. If you just want to learn GWT, stay with Java 8.
4. In **Additional Libraries and Frameworks**, check **☑ Google Web Toolkit**.
5. In **GWT SDK**, fill in the path to your GWT installation.
6. Check **☑ Create sample application** and introduce a fully qualified class name for the main class.

[image: New Project Wizard]

7. Click **Next**, and fill in the rest of needed info for your new project (this has nothing to do with GWT).

You'll end up with something like this:

[image]

If you followed the steps closely, the sample project should be fully functional. IntelliJ should've created a Run configuration for you, too, so you can run the GWT app right away and see it in action:

[image]

This is all explained in the official [help documentation for IntelliJ 2020.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/creating-a-module-with-a-gwt-facet.html), which was the last version to include GWT support out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the GWT project builders from IntelliJ or Eclipse. Both generate projects which use the same class path for client and server. In todays GWT development it is common to use a separate class path for client and server.

Depending on the server you prefer to use, choose:

https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes

in case you want to use Jetty or Tomcat on the server side or:

https://github.com/NaluKit/gwt-maven-springboot-archetype

in case you want to use Spring Boot.